# Unable to see response body from HTTPWebRequest when status is 400

Tags: windows-phone-7, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

In the following, ar.GetResponseAsString() just throws an exception.

Here is my code:

```
AsyncCallback GetTheResponse = ar =>
{
    try
    {
        var result = ar.GetResponseAsString();
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("ResponseStream:::{0}", result));
        callback(result, null);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

***What am I doing wrong?***

Comment: What is the exception message, please?

Comment: "The remote server returned an error: NotFound."  The problem is, I have replicated that same call using Whurl: https://whurl.heroku.com
and there is also a response body even though the status is 400 (which is the part I am trying to get to now):   {
  "user": {
    "errors": {
      "password": "is too short (minimum is 4 characters)"
    }
  },
  "error": {
    "httpCode": 400,
    "message": "Invalid parameters for user"
  }
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Catch the WebException that the 400 is throwing then grab the response from the exception message.  That's where your error response is hiding

Comment: yep...

  AsyncCallback GetTheResponse = ar =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var result = ar.GetResponseAsString();
                        callback(result, null);
                    }
                    catch (WebException ex)
                    {
                        Stream stream = ex.Response.GetResponseStream();
                        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                        string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        Debug.WriteLine(result);
                    }